# Passing checkbox value from .html page to .js file (not mvc)

Tags: checkbox

I need to pass a checkbox value from my .html page to a separate .js file. 
the .js file doesn't share a window, I cant use jQuery, and it's not MVC so no tempdata or controllers etc.
Any ideas?
Thanks

```
if(checkboxid == true){
  function myfunction(){
    //do stuff
  }
}
```

and in a separate file + window..

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxid" name="checkboxid" checked>
<input type="hidden" id="checkboxid" name="checkboxid" value="false">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully sure what you mean, but would this be a solution:

```
if (document.getElementById("checkboxid").checked) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I don't think that would work unless it's on the same page? I have to move the value from a configuration page, to some JavaScript acting on another page in a separate file

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found two solutions, 
one was to use localstorage,

```
var value = document.getElementById("value");
localStorage.setItem('key', value);
```

And the way I actually ended up doing it was to piggy-back it on a Web-API going from the same form.